# How do I version code with Django, Angular2, and Webpack?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django, angular, webpack

I am using Django + Angular 2 + Webpack, in Django I have created URL to render my app (http://example.com/user/beta), so first my index.html get rendered & index contains my angular 2 stuffs, since I am using webpack everything is bundled in main, vendor & polyfill, my structure is like this:

```
app
 |
 |__angular
 |     |
 |     |
 |     |___src
 |     |___typings
 |     |___package.json, tsconfig.json, webpack.config.js
 |
 |
 |__static
 |     |__css
 |     |__dist <this contains bundle files which got complied by webpack>
 |
 |
 |__templates
 |     |
 |     |___index.html
 |     |___app
            |__<all template files>
```

Here all static files got stored to CDN & there it seems js files is getting cached so new changes is not reflecting, to avoid that i have to manually version my js files like `main.bundle.v.01.js`, I want to change bundle file versions everytime I want to deploy it to test/production, so this manual work goes away, for this I had to do some changes in webpack.config for versioning & place those in index.html, but since index.html is not in control of webpack that can't be done, so I need to find a way that webpack resolves angular app code also do versioning of those bundle file & replace it in index.html

Answer (score 1):

The solution I used can be found in the following template

```
https://github.com/dkarchmer/django-aws-template
```

Unfortunately, it is based on Gulp (not Webpack), but you should be able to easily emulate the same flow from Webpack (or switch to Gulp).

Basically, the last step on my webapp's gulp flow is to use regular impressions to modify the top level index.html generated by Gulp, and move it to the templates directory:

```
gulp.task('templates', ['build'], () => {
  // Black Magic to convert all static references to use django's 'static' templatetags
  return gulp.src(config.dist + '/*.html')
        .pipe(replace(/href="app([/]\S*)"/g, 'href="{% static \'dist/webapp/app$1\' %}"'))
        .pipe(replace(/src="app([/]\S*)"/g, 'src="{% static \'dist/webapp/app$1\' %}"'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.templates));
});
```

where `config.templates = '../server/templates/dist/webapp'`. Obviously, you also need to `.gitignore` this directory. You end up with

As you can see, I basically replace any `href=app/foo/bar` with `href={% static 'dist/webapp/app/foo/bar' %}`

I do this, because I still want to be able to have the `{% static %}` template tag to change when doing development on my local computer, and when the statics come from a CDN in production.

The other thing you will notice on django template above is that the base template `server/templates/base.html` extends from

```
{% extends "dist/webapp/index.html" %}
```

`dist/webapp/index.html` is where my Gulp flow copied the modified `index.html`. Same for Image source files. Or in your flow, maybe you can just keep the `{% static %}` on the source files, and have webpack handle them.

```
|__templates
|     |
|     |__dist
|     |     |
|     |     |__ webapp/index.html
|     |
|     |___base.html
```

In my case, the Gulp flow strictly takes care of the stylesheets and scripts, so the rest is done by the `base.html` using regular Django techniques.

In another project where I used Angular, but wanted to still use Django to render and handle login and permissions, I added a single view that basically did

```
class AngularView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'dist/webapp/index.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(AngularView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

where `'dist/webapp/index.html'` is also the modified file built and copied by the Gulp flow (not under version control).

Obviously, the downside (at least for some) is the fact that you now have a two step process: 1) Build Statics, and 2) Django. But for me, that is equivalent to how `python manage.py collectstatic` works anyway.